# Discord Message Reaction Counting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to count the number of reactions each user has done in a channel. The typical process is to find a message then get the `reaction` and then use the `reaction.users()` method to get the users that have reacted to this message. But this is awfully slow for multipble messages. Is there a faster way of doing this?

I can already get 100 messages at a time with the channel history but then I have to get the user by asking the API for every message. This can't be the only way, right?

This is the code I have so far:

```py
count = 0

    limit = 100  # Adjust limit as needed (max 100)
    messages = []
    after = None
    last_after = None
    while True:
        history = ctx.channel.history(limit=limit, before=after)

        async for message in history:
            messages.append(message)
        
        after = messages[-1]

        if after == last_after:
            break

        last_after = after

        if count%10:
            print("Crawled " + str(count*100) + " Messages")

        count+=1
    
    reactions = {}

    for message in messages:
        if len(message.reactions) == 0:
            continue

        for reaction in message.reactions:
            if reaction.emoji != "":
                continue

            async for user in reaction.users():
                try:
                    reactions[user.id] = (user.display_name, reactions[user.id][-1]+1)
                except:
                    reactions[user.id] = (user.display_name, 1)
```